# Prove that $f^{-1}$SSE in SSE = SST - SSTR is the pooled unbiased estimate of the common covariance $\Sigma$ where f = n-J

Tags: multivariate-analysis, linear-algebra

At the onset I know I need to prove that $E(f^{-1}) = \Sigma$

I just don't know how to go about doing this.

I know $\frac{SSE}{\sigma^2}$ follows a $\chi^2$ distribution with, I believe, n-J degrees of freedom.

Can I extend this property now into multivariate statistics? I looked online and one method was;

$E[\frac{SSE}{n-J}]$ = $E[\frac{SSE}{n-J}\frac{\sigma}{\sigma}]$ for which the expectation of $\frac{SSE}{\sigma^2}$ is the respective degrees of freedom which would be n-J and thus the n-J terms cancel and we're left with $\sigma$.

Is it the same idea for a pooled covariance matrix?

Thank you in advance!